# Weird error in my Java code: "Unknown entityIOException"

Tags: java, ioexception

In Java, I was trying to make a button that runs Lua script when clicked. But I got that error:

```
public void onClick() {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/storage/emulated/0/Download/test.lua");
                try {
                    onClick();
                    } catch(IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

What should I do?

I tried to make a button in Java that runs Lua script when clicked, but I got an error.

Comment: Include the stacktrace. You also likely need to run the script using `lua`'s interpreter, or compile it beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. No need to answer.

```
public void onClick() throws IOException {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/storage/emulated/0/Download/navtex1.lua");
                try {
                    onClick();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                }
            }
```

Comment: You did not remove the error at all - just ignored it. The error can (and will) still be thrown, but now you'll simply be blissfully unaware of something not working. This is a _dangerous_ "solution", and not at all something I'd recommend for others to use.

Comment: ok thats a good thing. easy.